# why cumulative value adding same multiple values at one time in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

I am using Query to calculate cumulative values like :

```
..sum(Total) over(order by Total desc) As Cumulative
```

But it calculates the same value at a time.

Here is my output:

```
Error type  Total   Cumulative
E1          10      10
E2          5       20
E3          5       20
E4          3       26
E5          3       26
```

I would like the following:

```
Error type  Total   Cumulative
E1          10      10
E2          5       15
E3          5       20
E4          3       23
E5          3       26
```

I'm not sure how to figure this out.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Cumulative Sum by Group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971988/sql-server-cumulative-sum-by-group)

Comment: Just change the order by to: `(order by [Error type])` to get your desired output. Check this [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c6d9/1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think you are looking for this

```
select Error type , Total, 
sum(total) over (order by total desc Rows between Unbounded Preceding and  CURRENT ROW) as Cumulative 
from Table
```

Comment: If the downvoter could explain why this is bad, it would help everyone. It _looks_ bad to me, but I am not familiar enough with the newer keywords to say why. Care to share?

Comment: @ underscore_d But it helps people most of the time.