# Have a running total of costs for sql call to datatable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datatable

I'm creating a datatable using the sql call:

```
 SqlDataAdapter Adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) AS IncDate, SUM(IncCost) AS IncCost from Incomings GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103)", con);
```

which at the moment outputs

```
03/04/2016 - 13
05/04/2016 - 26
08/04/2016 - 5
13/04/2016 - 16
23/04/2016 - 23
```

I'm wondering how I can change my SQL query so that each cost is added to the previous one ie a running total. This would look something like

```
03/04/2016 - 13
05/04/2016 - 39
08/04/2016 - 44
13/04/2016 - 60
23/04/2016 - 83
```

Still no working solution as of yet and not sure how to go about it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Cumulative Sum by Group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971988/sql-server-cumulative-sum-by-group?rq=1). you can use subquery to achieve this

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate to that

Comment: thank you for this, although I got the error "Column 'Incomings.IncDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: You can do that using subquery as it described in the answer of above question, so your query would be something like this: select CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) AS IncDate, SUM(IncCost) AS IncCost, (select sum(IncCost) from Incomings t2 where t2.IncDate<=Incomings.IncDate ) as sumid from Incomings GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103)

Comment: thank you for this although I'm still getting an error

Comment: I executed the same query on my SSMS it works. what's your SQL Version?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2015 so whichever one is linked with that, the latest one I'm presuming

Comment: If want to do this in a SQL Query (which I recommend) you might want to learn to use the SQL Development tools. I suggest you open SQL Server Management Studio, connect and enter the query posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this and tweak as needed. It's easier to see what is happening if you do this in SSMS.

```
SELECT MyTable.IncDate AS IncDate, SUM(MyTable.IncCost) OVER (ORDER BY MyTable.IncDate) AS IncCost FROM
(
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) AS IncDate, 
    SUM(IncCost) AS IncCost
FROM 
    Incomings
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103)
) AS MyTable
ORDER BY MyTable.IncDate
```

Explanation: The inner SELECT statement allows us to do the grouping and get everything setup so the data is in the format that we want. Then we use the inner select like a table to do the SUM and OVER that allows us to get the running total.

Comment: thank you for this. I'm getting the error "Additional information: The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY". My SQL knowledge is very very very limited

Comment: thanks for your continued help. I'm now getting "Additional information: ORDER BY list of RANGE window frame cannot contain expressions of LOB type." whatever that means

Comment: It means that you're storing the IncDate values in something like a TEXT column. This would be a little easier if you posted the table schema. With that said. I've edited again to take that into account.

Comment: thank you for this. I'm using the data to create a chart: data1[i, 0] = Dt.Rows[i]["IncDate"];
                data1[i, 1] = Dt.Rows[i]["IncCost"]; and when I call IncDate and IncCost, it is showing up the original data that I have. I tried changed it to MyTable.IncCost, but no joy

Comment: thank you again, I think it's close. Although apparently "Column 'IncCost' does not belong to table ."

Comment: Refactored this to make it a lot easier to read and implement. Changed the aliasing to give you two columns (IncDate and IncCost)

Comment: Thank you Josh it worked perfectly, you are a legend! I'll be able to award the bounty tomorrow

Comment: I also think I understand what is happening but not completely

Comment: Final thing, this is very close to working although the dates seem to be a day off. So any ones for the 8th April and the 30th of April are showing up as the 7th April and 29th instead. thank you for your continued help josh!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105959/discussion-between-josh-and-stuart).

Comment: Hi Josh, quick one. Is this type of query known as a correlated subquery?

Comment: No. In order to be a correlated subquery the inner query must use values from the outer. This is the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ssms-2012 or above then try this query:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) AS IncDate, SUM(IncCost) over (order by IncDate) AS IncCost from Incomings GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103)
```

Comment: thank you for this although I'm getting the error "Column 'Incomings.IncDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" when I run it

Comment: try this query select CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103) AS IncDate, SUM(IncCost) over (order by IncDate) AS IncCost from Incomings GROUP BY IncDate ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103)

Comment: No joy for this either. Thanks though