# How to get cumulative totals

Tags: sql, sql-server

In following example i'm getting daily totals. I need to get cumulative totals relevant to the DPetAcNo.

```
    SELECT
DPetAcNo as AcNo,
SUM(DPetAmount) as PetTotal
FROM PettyDetail
WHERE DPetComCode='15'
and DPetLocCode='01'
and DPetDate=CONVERT(date,'20181113',111)
group by
DPetAcNo
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Cumulative Sum by Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971988/sql-server-cumulative-sum-by-group)

Comment: WHERE MONTH(date) = 11 and YEAR(date) = 2018

Comment: Be ***very*** clear about the exact output you want.  Show us an example of the results you need.  *(Add them to the question by editing the question, don't add a comment or an answer.)*

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to solve this is:

```
SELECT DPetAcNo as AcNo, SUM(DPetAmount) as PetTotal,
       SUM(SUM(DPetAmount)) OVER (ORDER BY DPetAcNo) as Running_PetTotal
FROM PettyDetail
WHERE DPetComCode = '15' AND
      DPetLocCode = '01' AND
      DPetDate = '20181113'
GROUP BY DPetAcNo;
```

If this does not do what you want, then you need to be quite clear on what doesn't work and on what result set you actually want.